# Adding an image in an option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Guys i am in a bit of a pickle over here . Need to add an image on top of the "Text given in an option tags". However, whenever i add an image nested in the option tag it wont show in the code but it does work once i put it through the firebug after the page is rendered.
Please help me out here.
Here is the sample code and the full code is in the end on JSfiddle:

```
  <div class="GreySection">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">  
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist"aria-multiselectable="true">
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="panel panel-default panel-top-gap">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div id="selectcontrolm">
<select name="cassr" multiple class="cassr">
<option value="A"><img src="images/grammar.png" >Spelling &amp; Grammar</option>
<option value="A">Reading Age</option>
<option value="A">Sentiment</option>
  <option value="A">Video Length</option>
<option value="A">Word count</option>
<option value="A">All Topics</option>
<option value="A">Number of images</option>
<option value="A">Image size</option>
<option value="Bugatti">Font size</option>
<option value="Chrysler">Page speeds</option>
<option value="Daihatsu">All keywords</option>
<option value="Ford">Mobile UX</option>
<option value="GM">Taxonomy</option>
<option value="Honda">SEO Relevance</option>
<option value="Infiniti">Entities</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSfiddle link to the code [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4fzg9xx/4/)

Comment: Is there any other way i mean i can use div instead of an option tag right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jquery for this. It works in all modern browser as well. [Selectmenu](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes